# In a linux shared hosting account content node app and Wordpress web, WordPress web using main domain and node app using a subdomain is it possible

Tags: node.js, wordpress, subdomain, web-hosting

I have a one hosting account and one domain with Wordpress hosted in it.I need to put **Node.js  base Expresss web application to subdomain**.

Ex- www.abc.com = Wordpress website 
    app.abc.com = Node.js base Expresss web application.

**Is it possible to do with one hosting account and one domain that i have?If it is possible how to configure the subdomain link to Expresss web application?**

(my hosting account support multiple websites and it is a linux shared hosting account)

Comment: if your hosting support both php and nodejs yes you can but probably not.

Comment: why ,Can you explain it please?

Comment: Do you have ssh access to the server? If you do, you can do whatever you want, including having an express app, and a wordpress on the same server.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande thanx for the answer,I have the ssh access but i don’t know  how to point the subdomain to the express app,Is it possible without virtual host creating.Reason is host providers not give apache config edit in shared hosting.if anything wrong please correct me

Comment: You don't have root ssh access?